# Java Script to unhide div based on calculated value

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with a form where values are entered.  My javascript totals the values inputted at the bottom when the submit botton is clicked (onclick="runTotal(this.form)), but now I need it to not only total the form but to also unhide a specific div based on the value of the total.

Basically I need if the field "total" equals any of the following unhide div

0-85 unhide div id red
125-86 unhide div id yellow
126 or more unhide div id green

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Use CSS to hide/unhide (toggling `display:none`). Write a simple logic in your `runTotal` function to check for the conditions you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your div originally hidden using

```
<div id="your-div" hidden></div>
```

I would suggest you use jquery to hide and unhide that div.  It's simple as:

```
$("#your-div").show();
```

You can just put that line in your runTotal method.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery for a simple, robust approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#totalBox').change(function () {
        var total = $(this).val();
        if(total <= 85) { $("#red").toggle(); }
        else if(total > 85 && <= 125) { $("#yellow").toggle(); }
        else if(total > 125) { $("#green").toggle(); }
    }
});
```

**Where**

```
#totalBox = your "total" input textbox's ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DIV to be displayed is initially set to display:"none";

```
var oldRunTotal = runTotal; 
runTotal = function(form){
  var id = "green",
      total = oldRunTotal(form);
  if (total < 0) return;
  else if (total < 86) id = "red";
  else if (total < 126) id = "yellow";
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
};
```